# How to edit a file saved in string using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to edit the file saved in a string using sed. As per the below example, I want to change some pattern in the php.ini file. Below example will allow only to change what is saved in the string.

```
[root@server ~]# PHPINI=/etc/php.ini
[root@server ~]# sed "s/somepattern/changedpattern/" <<< "$PHPINI"
```

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sed -i.bak "s/somepattern/changedpattern/" "$PHPINI"` ?

Comment: @JoaoMorais: Unfortunately not all flavors of `sed` support the `-i` option...

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoaoMorais it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the herestring syntax which passes a string on standard input. You should instead pass the name of the file as an argument:

```
sed 's/somepattern/changedpattern/' /etc/php.ini
```

To overwrite the existing file, the standard method is to write to a temporary file and then overwrite the original:

```
sed 's/somepattern/changedpattern/' /etc/php.ini > tmp && mv tmp /etc/php.ini
```

Some versions of sed support "in-place" editing (which does more or less the same in the background):

```
sed -i.bak 's/somepattern/changedpattern/' /etc/php.ini
```

This creates a backup of the original file with a `.bak` suffix.

If the filename is contained within a variable, then simply use that instead

```
php_ini=/etc/php.ini
sed -i.bak 's/somepattern/changedpattern/' "$php_ini"
```

Note my use of lowercase variable names. Uppercase ones should be reserved for use by the shell.

Comment: I am writing a bash script in which the file name got saved in the string and then I have to edit it with sed(or any other way).

Comment: @prado hopefully my edit makes it clear how the filename can be a variable (it doesn't really make much difference).